# indexed though blocked by robots.txt laravel

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.5

I have some urls warnings in google search console. The project it`s made in laravel 5.5

```
indexed though blocked by robots.txt
```

In the header app layout i have:

```
<meta name="Robots" content="index,follow" />
```

One of the errors is **Server Error (5xx)** for this urls:

```
https://mydomain/remove-item-cart/26101
```

I don`t want to be indexed the remove-item-cart so in **robots.txt** i have blocked:

```
Disallow: /remove-item-cart/
```

The error probably occurs because of the meta "index" - but i am not sure.

The remove-item-cart is a **get** method in **web.php**

```
Route::get('/remove-item-cart/{id}', 'CartController@removeItem')->name('removeItemCart');
```

where is removing the item from cart, after that `return redirect()->route('cart');`

How it`s the best practice in laravel to noindex those get method???
Should i remove the "Disallow" line from robots and in the blade header layouts set "noindex" in meta depending on url request?

Answer (score 0):

To save some time and effort here, if you are unsure of how to generate a robots.txt file yourself, I'd recommend a package such as https://github.com/ellisio/laravel-5-robots. It has a fairly elegant solution to creating them programmatically.

Answer (score 0):

in the  section of your page.

meta name=”robots” content=”noindex”

If you want to prevent Google crawlers alone, use the following tag –

meta name=”Googlebot” content=”noindex”